# Double digit values for date

Tags: forms

I can not figure this out for the life of me, I am trying to have doubt digit values for  the day and month in my module using form api, I have tried this with the date api and still no luck,

my function looks like this

```
function set_dob_year_range($form_element) {
$form_element['year']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(range(1900, 2012));
return $form_element;
}

    $form['dob'] = array(
        '#type'  => 'date',
        '#title' => t('Date Of Birth'),
        '#default_value' => array(
            'month' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'm'), 
            'day' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'd'), 
            'year' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'Y'),
        ),
        '#after_build' => array('set_dob_year_range'),
        '#required' => TRUE
    );
```

using in on the month should count the months values as 01 02 03 but instead its using 1 2 3, thing for the days it should be 01 02 03 instead its using 1 2 3.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The date formats are not passing through to the values for anyone that is confused.
[image]

Comment: Here are some [date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). @Epok has the right answer.

Comment: the date formats are not passing through to the values –

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of where the output is not what you are expecting?

Comment: im using firebug to go to the values to see what they are and the values are 1 2 3 ect instead of 01 02 03 and I did try m and d in the fields, it was actually the very 1st thing i tried

Comment: And you are sure the #default_value is working? If you type 'foo' for the month, you see 'foo'?

Comment: if I type foo the date is still coming through it somehow

Comment: Your custom date has nothing to do with the output. You need to alter the form select options to actually contain the two digit dates/months.

Answer (score 2):

You should try, i think it will work

```
format_date(time(), 'custom', 'm');
format_date(time(), 'custom', 'd');
```

Comment: the date formats are not passing through to the values

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see the output with the missing leading zeroes, are they going into the database like that?  If not whatever is pulling the values is probably turning them into integers.

Comment: im using firebug to go to the values to see what they are and the values are 1 2 3 ect instead of 01 02 03

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and tell me changes,

```
function set_dob_year_range($form_element) {
$form_element['year']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(range(1900, 2012));
return $form_element;
}

    $form['dob'] = array(
        '#type'  => 'date_select',
        '#title' => t('Date Of Birth'),
        '#default_value' => array(
            'month' => str_pad(format_date(time(), 'custom', 'm'), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 
            'day' => str_pad(format_date(time(), 'custom', 'd'), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 
            'year' => format_date(time(), 'custom', 'Y'),
        ),
        '#after_build' => array('set_dob_year_range'),
        '#required' => TRUE
    );
```

Comment: It did not work, everything stayed the same =/